# VHDL:slow to fast clock

Tags: clock, fpga, ethernet

I am working on Ethernet and FPGAs. The serial data is arriving at CPLD at a baud rate of 115200bps through a socket.I need to latch it to a higher clock which FPGA expects..say 10 MHz . I do not have an option for flash memory to store the serial data. All i have is a CPLD with 256 macro cells to do this.

could anyone help me in achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at how a UART works.  This is an asynchronous interface (the A in UART), you will need to over-sample the data in the CPLD.